# Is there a survey of real-time internet bottlenecks?

Tags: internet, connection

What can a DSL customer expect the ISP to do to ensure good internet connectivity aside from providing the contracted level of "last mile" bit rate?

I almost always get the 1Mb/s data rate I am paying for when I use a site like `speedtest.net` to check.  My problem is that in recent days I get a lot of timeouts.  This is a new problem, and I would estimate that 7 days back I was not seeing this problem to nearly this extent.  For example from the superuser.com front page, I hit `Ask Question` to write this question and after some delay I received:

`Firefox can't find server at superuser.com`.

I am getting similar timeouts on various `Wordpress` blogs, `economist.com`, `google.com`, `finance.yahoo.com` `stackoverflow.com` or if there is no timeout, it simply takes on the order of minutes just to load their front page.  Another common problem is that the page only partially loads, so perhaps the style sheets are still in transit and so the website displays in the wrong fonts and sizes for an unusually long period.  Mostly I am hitting North American or European websites from the Philippines.

Is there a real-time website I can look at to see if there is a bottleneck problem between continents or along major optical routes?

Comment: just search for "worldwide or Global internet speed stats" and get places like, Example  internettrafficreport.com  . Do speed tests in your country, http://www.dslreports.com/speedtest?more=1  then across the whole world, if the continuous speeds are always the same, then it isnt your speed. It sound more like a DNS problem. you could ping your dns or test different dns servers. If connect TO is slow, but pages roll in fast, or it does not find IPs fast, it could be DNS.